# InitializeComponent does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, avaloniaui, avalonia

I am new to Avalonia and now face the issue, that the function `InitializeComponent` does not exist in the current context. I do not have this error in any other view. I hope you can help me find the problem.

MainWindow.axaml.cs:

```
using Avalonia.Controls;
```

namespace MBotSoftware.Views;

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

MainWindow.axaml:

```
<Window xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vm="using:MBotSoftware.ViewModels"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MBotSoftware"
        mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="800" d:DesignHeight="450"
        x:Class="MBotSoftware.Views.MainWindow"
        Icon="/Assets/avalonia-logo.ico"
        Title="MBotSoftware">
    <StackPanel>
        <views:MBotLandingView />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be the mismatch of Avalonia version you use and the version of the template. If this is the case adding this in your axaml file should fix the problem.

```
using Avalonia.Markup.Xaml;

private void InitializeComponent()
{
   AvaloniaXamlLoader.Load(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know this error indicates that there is no class that can execute `InitializeComponent();` method.
This is because C# code cannot be associated with markup file.
And this is because you might have errors in your markup.
So please check errors in your `MainWindow.axaml` and try to Clear Solution.

Maybe this line is the problem, if you deleted ViewModels directory:

```
        xmlns:vm="using:MBotSoftware.ViewModels"
```

This is only my understanding of that issue. But in a wast majority of such cases, careful check for markup errors is often the key.